# Html mailto: HTML e-mail link Open when double click on input field using jQuery .dblclick

Tags: jquery, html

I've a following input field for email address. In this field I can edit it's value after click on it. Now I want to double click on it. So it will be open **Html mailto: HTML e-mail link**. How can I do this ? I used following code. But it's not opening. Any help ?

**Html Code:**

```
<tr>
<td>Work Email</td>
<td id="mailto"><input value="<?php echo $res['email'] ?>" type="text" name="email"   
id="email" placeholder="Email address"/></td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mailto").dblclick(function(){   
  <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test subject">mail</a>
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
**HTML**:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Work Email</td>
<td id="mailto"><input value="<?php echo $res['email'] ?>" type="text" name="email"   
id="email" placeholder="Email address"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#email").dblclick(function(){   
        window.open('mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test subject');
  });
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/go8mdkh6/1/) here

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not working. When I double click on Work Email field it's not opening the mailto: but I see a link is created bellow the field. e.g mail.

Comment: Ok.. then change codes inside callback to `window.open('mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=test subject')`

Comment: Ok. I'm trying it now.

Comment: Ah, My outlook is not working properly. But I believe your code will be working :)

Comment: Great Answer. It's working now. Can I open it in same page ? Now it's open in another tab.

Comment: To open it in the same page, add another argument `'_self'` in the `window.open` after the link. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/go8mdkh6/2/)

Comment: Thank You Johnroe Paulo Cañamaque.